# "The launch timed out and was terminated" error with Bumblebee on Linux

Tags: linux, cuda, optimus

When running a long kernel (especially in debug mode with some memory checking) on a CUDA-enabled GeForce GPU with Bumblebee, I get the following error:

> CUDA error 6: the launch timed out and was terminated

This seems to be caused by the NVIDIA driver's watchdog. A solution is available [here](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x). However, why is this happening while using Bumblebee and `optirun` to run a simple CUDA kernel (i.e. I do not use my NVIDIA GPU for display)?

The command I used to launch the program is:

```
optirun [cuda-memcheck] ./my_program program_options
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution (found [here](http://blog.ale-re.net/2013/05/profiling-cuda-applications-with.html)) was to use the `--no-xorg` option for `optirun`, i.e.:

```
optirun --no-xorg [cuda-memcheck or cuda-gdb] ./my_program program_options
```

Indeed, the default behavior of `optirun` is to create a secondary X server which will then be subject to the driver's watchdog. By using the `--no-xorg` option, we can avoid the unnecessary consequences of this extra X server. This new option is available since [Bumblebee 3.2](https://raw.github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/master/doc/RELEASE_NOTES_3_2).

It also provides a way to use `cuda-gdb` and avoid the following error:

> fatal:  All CUDA devices are used for display and cannot be used while
>   debugging. (error code = 24)

Comment: Even with the `--no-xorg` flag I still get timeout errors for a large enough (slow enough) program. Any ideas?

Comment: I never had the issue again after that, so I really don't know what that could be this time.