# CUDA C Timeout on Kernel Call: "the launch timed out and was terminated"

Tags: c, cuda

I'm having an issue with calling a matrix addition kernel that causes a timeout on matrices larger than 255x255. For further information, I'm compiling with -arch=sm_21 and running on a MacBook Pro. I've tried using different sized blocks and threads.

The matrix struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int n, m; /* Define an n-rows by m-columns matrix */
    double* data;
} c_matrix;
```

Initializing the matrix and the wrapper for adding the matrix:

```
extern "C"
c_matrix *new_c_matrix(int i, int j) {

c_matrix *m = (c_matrix *)malloc(sizeof(*m));
if(m == NULL)
    return NULL;

    m->data = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * i * j);
    if(m->data == NULL) {
        free(m);
        return NULL;
    }

    m->n = i;
    m->m = j;

    return m;
}

extern "C"
void c_matrix_add(const c_matrix *m1, const c_matrix *m2, c_matrix *m) {
    /*  We only need 4 comparisons because we can assume
     *  transitivity of ints */
    if(m1->m != m2->m || m1->n != m2->n || m1->m != m->m
        || m1->n != m2->n)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    double *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
    handle_error( cudaMalloc(&d_a, m1->m * m1->n * sizeof(double)) );
    handle_error( cudaMalloc(&d_b, m1->m * m1->n * sizeof(double)) );
    handle_error( cudaMalloc(&d_c, m1->m * m1->n * sizeof(double)) );

    handle_error( cudaMemcpy(d_a, m1->data, m1->m * m1->n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
    handle_error( cudaMemcpy(d_b, m2->data, m2->m * m2->n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );

    dim3 dimBlock(16, 16);
    dim3 dimGrid((m1->m + dimBlock.x - 1) / dimBlock.x, (m1->n + dimBlock.y - 1) / dimBlock.y);

    cu_matrix_add<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, m1->m * m1->n);

    handle_error( cudaMemcpy(m->data, d_c, m->m * m->n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );

    // cudaFree( d_c );
    cudaFree( d_b );
    cudaFree( d_a );
}
```

And the kernel itself:

```
__global__ void cu_matrix_add(const double *d_a, const double *d_b, double *d_c, int element_count) {
    unsigned short tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    while( tid < element_count ) {
        d_c[tid] = d_a[tid] + d_b[tid];
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}
```

It's timing out on the `handle_error( cudaMemcpy(m->data, d_c, m->m * m->n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );` when I attempt to copy the device matrix back to the host matrix.

Comment: Have you already googled your question and tried the solutions in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185117/cudamemcpy-errorthe-launch-timed-out-and-was-terminated) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335808/the-launch-timed-out-and-was-terminated-error-with-bumblebee-on-linux) posts?

Comment: @JackOLantern - I had already looked at both of them. I tried the first solution and had gotten no further error information than `the launch timed out and was terminated`. As for the second one, I couldn't get optirun/bumblebee working on OS X.

Comment: printf is your friend! First ensure that the timeout is really on the memcpy.... if you don't use cudaDeviceSynchronize the timeout might actually be happening on the kernel, since cudaMemcpy will wait for it to finish. Also, it pays off to use cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D for working with matrices...

Comment: The solution as indicated in the first link provided by @JackOLantern is to reduce the running time of your kernel, to avoid the timeout watchdog.  Please re-read the answer given by talonmies in that link, especially the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @RobertCrovella - Thanks! After reworking the kernel, I got it working. I was afraid that there was something wrong with the kernel, but it appears it just did too much work.